# Get the metadata of PSD file with PHP

Tags: php, imagemagick, metadata, psd

I want to fetch the metadata of a PSD file in PHP with ImageMagick.

I only know how to do this for JPEG or other images types (exif, iptc and so on) but don't know how to read the metadata of a PSD file.

So if you set a comment / copyright in Photoshop and save the PSD, when reading the PSD, the PHP script should be able to read this comment and also some other meta data.

Opening PSD files is already done, so I just want to read these additional metadata.

I use PHP on a managed server with ImageMagick support.

for Javascript I found psd.js https://github.com/noaheverett/psd.js

Comment: Also see the related question in the sidebar.

Comment: Which one? I already use Imagemagick for opening the psd files successfully. So i need just the part with the metadata fetching from the psd.

Comment: it's only 25 related links. Is it too much to go through that list without being pointed to a particular one?

Comment: none in particular. I just noticed there is links to PSD readers and SDKs in those, so I figured you might find those useful. Was really just trying to give you puzzle pieces because I doubt someone will post *the* solution.

Comment: the sdks are not for php and the psd readers are not that what i want. i want just an easy solution to read the meta data. i have already done all the functions for opening and processing psd files in php with imagemagick. no, the other questions and their answers didnt help me.

Comment: so its not a duplicate, because i already can open these files. thats a whole different question

Comment: The SDK is largely language agnostic and describes the file format. But very well then, wait until someone gives you a copy and paste solution.

Comment: and the sdk also the one for php is written in c (c++), i think you misunderstood my question =(

Comment: i think i do understand the question. just trying to make you follow leads while waiting ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I saw that you can extract XMP using:

```
identify -verbose file
```

As far as I know PSD is making use of [XMP](http://www.adobe.com/products/xmp/). Additionally there are additional PHP libraries like [xmpphptoolkit](http://xmpphptoolkit.sourceforge.net/) to deal with metadata specifically.

Comment: I need it for PHP, I cant use the command line of imagemagick directly on the server. and that toolkit seems a bit to big for this task and dont know if this works the way i want (seems very old and alpha, doenst support psd?)

Comment: @Daniel: *Seems* and the like: If you don't want to, then let it be. But please then don't ask.

Comment: im currently downloading and then testing this one, but it seems its an php extension i would have to install on the server, but that would not work as i have a managed server and identify doesnt show data like the comment (meta data) and so on

Comment: its only for root servers and written in c / c++ so i cant use this one

Comment: @DanielRuf: You can compile on a compatible server (e.g. virtualize the managed one your own) and then use the compiled binary on the managed server. It might not always work but some managed servers allow you to use your own php.ini and extensions.

Comment: well, this is no solution for the managed server hosting of my hosting provider (which I am using)

Comment: Yes, it's not always an option. However, it sounds a bit *mis*managed to me if the hoster is not able to manage the server for your (but only for his own sake of management) needs. A misname for such a thing "managed server" if it is a "crippled server". Anyway I would talk to them and discuss your needs otherwise switch hosters.

Comment: well, this would cost me 120 euros per hour ;-) and no, I would never switch my hosting provider. Well, actually it is just a normal hosting solution on a shared server with many customers and a full managed server just for me would cost much more ;-) but thanks for the tip